# Product pagination for customer group not working in Enterprise Edition

Tags: magento-enterprise, product-list, customer-group

I am using Magento Enterprise ver. 1.14.0.1, when I log in with a particular customer group(Sales Representative) other than general customer group category product list not working as per general customer group. I add two identical products in admin both are simple products, pagination is not working as it works in general customer group, default I can see 1 product loaded for (Sales Representative) whereas for general it has 12.

Debug code and found that product collection give result 1 below is a query which gives all proper result but on the page, it displays 1 product

```
 SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`,
    `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, 
    IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, 
        price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, 
    `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, 
    `price_index`.`tier_price`
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index`
    ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id
    AND cat_index.store_id=1
    AND cat_index.category_id = '54'
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index`
    ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id
    AND price_index.website_id = '1'
    AND price_index.customer_group_id = '6'
```

Comment: Do you happen to have the Customer Group Catalog by Amasty installed? [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-group-catalog-by-amasty.html)